# wrong class format Bulding a Package from Java 7 to Java 8

Tags: java, export, drools, drools-guvnor, guvnor

i have two installations of Guvnor 5.6.0.Final, one (Machine A) is runnig over Java 7, the second one (Machine B) is runnig over Java 8.
I made an export of the repository from Machine A and imported into Machine B.
Every time i do the Build Package i have this stack trace

```
Sep 29, 2014 9:58:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract org.drools.guvnor.client.rpc.BuilderResult org.drools.guvnor.client.rpc.ModuleService.buildPackage(java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.String) throws com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: wrong class format
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: wrong class format
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:263)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1188)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromVariantTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1244)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeArgumentsFromSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getPackage(Scope.java:2283)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedTypeReference.getTypeBinding(QualifiedTypeReference.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.resolveTypesFor(SourceTypeBinding.java:1370)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.getMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findStaticMethod(CompilationUnitScope.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findSingleStaticImport(CompilationUnitScope.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findSingleImport(CompilationUnitScope.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInImports(CompilationUnitScope.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInTypes(CompilationUnitScope.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:752)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:464)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:389)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:410)
    at org.drools.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:46)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:103)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAll(PackageBuilder.java:1196)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileRules(PackageBuilder.java:1015)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAllRules(PackageBuilder.java:946)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:938)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:444)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:422)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.PackageAssemblerBase.addDrl(PackageAssemblerBase.java:311)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.PackageAssemblerBase.loadFunctionsToBuilder(PackageAssemblerBase.java:176)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.PackageAssemblerBase.setUpPackage(PackageAssemblerBase.java:126)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.PackageAssembler.compile(PackageAssembler.java:67)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryModuleOperations.buildModule(RepositoryModuleOperations.java:579)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryModuleOperations.buildModule(RepositoryModuleOperations.java:550)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryModuleOperations$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.buildModule(RepositoryModuleOperations$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryModuleService.buildPackage(RepositoryModuleService.java:302)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryModuleService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.buildPackage(RepositoryModuleService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.ModuleServiceServlet.buildPackage(ModuleServiceServlet.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.createNameEnvironmentAnswer(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:287)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:258)
    ... 87 more
```

Same Error But with a differente stack trace if i do "Rebuild all packages Binaries"

```
 WARN  29-09 10:04:14,663 (LoggingHelper.java:warn:81)   
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: wrong class format
    at org.drools.template.parser.DefaultTemplateRuleBase.readRule(DefaultTemplateRuleBase.java:148)
    at org.drools.template.parser.DefaultTemplateRuleBase.<init>(DefaultTemplateRuleBase.java:62)
    at org.drools.template.parser.TemplateDataListener.<init>(TemplateDataListener.java:74)
    at org.drools.template.parser.TemplateDataListener.<init>(TemplateDataListener.java:50)
    at org.drools.template.DataProviderCompiler.compile(DataProviderCompiler.java:58)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.util.BRDRTPersistence.marshal(BRDRTPersistence.java:57)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.contenthandler.drools.BRLContentHandler.getSourceDRL(BRLContentHandler.java:84)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.contenthandler.drools.BRLContentHandler.compile(BRLContentHandler.java:61)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.PackageAssemblerBase.compile(PackageAssemblerBase.java:91)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.PackageAssemblerBase.buildAsset(PackageAssemblerBase.java:75)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.PackageAssembler.addAsset(PackageAssembler.java:132)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.PackageAssembler.loadAllButDRLAssets(PackageAssembler.java:115)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.PackageAssembler.loadAssets(PackageAssembler.java:105)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.PackageAssembler.buildPackage(PackageAssembler.java:97)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.builder.PackageAssembler.compile(PackageAssembler.java:68)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryModuleOperations.buildModule(RepositoryModuleOperations.java:579)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryModuleOperations.buildModule(RepositoryModuleOperations.java:550)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryModuleOperations$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.buildModule(RepositoryModuleOperations$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryModuleService.buildPackage(RepositoryModuleService.java:302)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryModuleService.buildPackage(RepositoryModuleService.java:277)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryModuleService.rebuildPackages(RepositoryModuleService.java:141)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.RepositoryModuleService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.rebuildPackages(RepositoryModuleService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.ModuleServiceServlet.rebuildPackages(ModuleServiceServlet.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: wrong class format
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:263)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1188)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromVariantTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1244)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeArgumentsFromSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findImport(CompilationUnitScope.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findSingleImport(CompilationUnitScope.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInImports(CompilationUnitScope.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInTypes(CompilationUnitScope.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:752)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:464)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:389)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:410)
    at org.drools.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:46)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:103)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAll(PackageBuilder.java:1196)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAllRules(PackageBuilder.java:949)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:938)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:444)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:422)
    at org.drools.template.parser.DefaultTemplateRuleBase.readRule(DefaultTemplateRuleBase.java:139)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.createNameEnvironmentAnswer(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:287)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:258)
    ... 92 more
```

Is there a mode to import this repo on Java 8 in guvnor 5.6?

Every help is appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I faced with the same issue recently.

Drools 5.5.x should work on JDK 6, 7 and 8 but Eclipse ECJ needs to be upgraded from 3.5.1 to 4.5.1 if you use Java 8.

This fix the issue:

```
<!-- official drools dependencies -->
...
...

<!-- upgrade Eclipse ECJ for drools in order to it can work with Java 8 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Wow, that's an easy fix to an obscure error, thanks. Just a quick note, there's an extra `>` in `<version>4.5.1</version>`